# What 'large' surfaces are there?

Tags: reference-request, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I answered [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/377314/is-there-the-longest-geodesic) question on "is there a longest geodesic" by a kind of a joke, which I couldn't resist: the long line! Simply going by the name it had to be the 'longest geodesic'! I didn't bother explaining the joke, after all, a joke that requires explaining, is no joke at all, in my exoerience.

I cinsidered it a joke because I didn't know of a theory of such 'large' manifolds and I thought my intentions would be clear - they weren't apparently.

But then, much to my surprise, whilst researching something else entirely,  I came upon a classification of such 'large' surfaces! Unfortunately I didn't make a note of it. However, whilst trying to find where and what this result exactly is, I came upon a paper by Rafael Dahmen on embeddings of the long line in weakly complete vector spaces. These are spaces like $R^I$ for arbitrary $$. The paper is [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.05770) and titled: *Smooth Embeddings of the Long Line and other Non-Paracompact Manifolds into Locally Convex Spaces*.

Q. What I'm after is a paper or a book outlining the classification of such large surfaces.

I recall the source that I referenced a certain book, a handbook, from what I recall.  Unfortunately, I don't remember the title of the book or which source it was - other than the source was online. Hence the question.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bagpipe_theorem

Comment: @Mike Miller: That's it! Given the name of the theorem, I"m surprised I forgot it. Thanks!